# Average Random Integers

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that takes an integer as command-line argument, uses random to print `N` uniform random values between 0 and 1, and then prints their average value.

I'm not sure what arguments to put in the while loop so that random integers are repeated `n` times, `n` being the number from the user indicating the number of integers the random has to generate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Code is better than English, post it please.

Comment: It seems you are asking three different questions: 1) How to count from 1 to n in a loop, 2) How to create a random number in the range 0..1, 3) How to cimpute the average of numbers. All three problems were asked before, just try to find and combine the solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to execute a loop a specific number of times, I'd use a `for` loop

The following loop will iterate exactly `n` times, and It's what I personally use when I need to do something exactly `n` times.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    //insert body here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
public class UniformRandomNumbers1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int i;
        double total = 0.0; //(The sum of n, numbers)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            double rand = Math.random(); //(Random number between 0 & 1)
            total += rand; // Increment total by rand
            System.out.println(i + " = " + rand); // Prints value of n & corresponding double value 
        }
        double average = total / n; // Calculates average of n numbers
        System.out.println("Average = " + average); // Prints average of n numbers, Can i get an up vote? :) plz
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps anyone out there.

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are less useful than code + explanation.

Comment: Well, I'm not a Java expert, but I think the code abviously does what had been asked for. Maybe just add some comments to the code like "count from 1 to n", "get random number in range 0..1", and "compute average of random numbers".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pjs Thanks for the feedback I hope the comments I included are sufficient enough to be considered explanations. I am new here and I'm still learning to navigate the space.

Comment: @U.Windl Please view my comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = 0;
for (int current = 1; current <= n; n++) {
    double rand = Math.random();
    total += rand;
    System.out.println(currentN + "= " + rand);
}
System.out.println("Total = " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

under the assumption that your PRNG is behaving correcly you just need this:

```
main()
{
   printf("\n0.5");
   exit(0);
}
```

that's for N sufficiently large... computed in constant time. otherwise use the moving average formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

which requires only O(1) memory space instead of the naive O(N) approach

here the cut&paste java code:

```
public class Rolling {

    private int size;
    private double total = 0d;
    private int index = 0;
    private double samples[];

    public Rolling(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        samples = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) samples[i] = 0d;
    }

    public void add(double x) {
        total -= samples[index];
        samples[index] = x;
        total += x;
        if (++index == size) index = 0; // cheaper than modulus
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return total / size;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to post that on a different question?

Comment: "any help" would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever run a repeated loop averaging random numbers and the result was exactly `0.5`? Before suggesting such an answer you should prove it's valid.